# How to efficiently use NHibernate ISessionFactory in a multi-database same schema environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We are working on an MVC application and have an environment where all clients have their own copy of a database, all with the same schema.  There are cases where a user may need to access multiple client databases within one request.  I am trying to avoid creating an instance of ISessionFactory every time the application needs to open a new client database.  All other settings are the same, so really I just want a way to change the connection string of the ISessionFactory after it has been created.  From what I have been able research, it doesn't seem like this is possible.

Most people point to this [article](https://patrickhuber.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/change-connectionstring-nhibernate/) as the preferred solution, basically caching the configuration so it doesn't need to be reevaluated every time you call create a session factory with a different connection string.  This post is a few years old now, so I was wondering if anyone else had come up with a more efficient way of changing the connection string or handling this type of multiple tenant environment?

Comment: NHibernate does not have multi-tenancy support, check how Sharp Architecture deal with that: http://yellowfeather.co.uk/blog/multi-tenancy-on-sharp-architecture/

Comment: you could store your session factories in a dictionary and use as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I derived from `DriverConnectionProvider`, override `GetConnection` method to use the correct connection string for the current tenant. The logic to choose connection string is encapsulated in a Provider object:

```
public class HibernateConnectionProvider : NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public static IProvider<string> ConnectionStringProvider { private get; set; }

    protected override string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return ConnectionStringProvider.ProvideValue(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: In reading about others that have tried that approach and the NHibernate source code, it seems like you can run into trouble with [caching](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/ISessionFactory.cs#L33-L39).  Did you have to implement your own IConnectionProvider?

Comment: We only override the standard DriverConnectionProvider. Certainly we'll have to do extra works if we decide use 2nd level cache, but right now our product does not need it, and I don't think it'll be too difficult, as per Ayende: http://ayende.com/blog/1708/nhibernate-caching-the-secong-level-cache-space-is-shared.

Answer (score 0):

I believe delegating management of the database access within the MVC application is wrong!

This should be delegated to the DevOps. To do this you will need MVC application per customer, then you would not need to worry about code to support database selection although it comes at cost of extra application. However think this is smaller evil from both.

At current work we had this kind architecture (designed about the time of the post you shared) and it did lead to many problems. For example one customer needs feature A, that requires database migration B which implicates stop of all of the customer's service and often to unhandled situations.

Comment: Yes, in your case database schema are different so you cannot use one SessionFactory for that.

Comment: Nope the schema is the same all the times. However customer A needs update and this requires db update for customer B. Can you guarantee you will not have such discrepancies in future?

Comment: Yeah, now I understand what you meant. This can be difficult, I can only think of separate web farms for different version of the software/schema, once a customer database is upgraded, it needs to be moved to the correct web farm also. Might be a complicated operation, but should not be a big deal if you have good automation tool. I'm not very familiar with operation, though. Can you disclose some information about your solution?

Comment: We had the product like the one you are talking about - a monolothic application serving many customers and needs. Releases were rather challenges. The smallest period required to test and get release to live even smallest batches of updates was 2-3 months. This is why we went with solution that involves Octopus Deploy, Custom wrapper of the Octopus deploy and NuGET packages. We have assets - servers and the custom wrapper is a web application that does the job of installator using Octopus. This way we have list of customers installations and we can update customer easily at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Vladimir!